# Show that $\Pr\big(X_t=x \, | \, X_{1},\dots, X_{t-1}\big) \geq \nu_x$ implies $\Pr\big(X_t=x \, | \, Y_{1},\dots, Y_{t-1}\big) \geq \nu_x$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $\{X_t\}_t$ be a sequence of discrete random variables and assume that
\begin{equation}
\\Pr\big(X_t=x \, | \, X_{1},\dots, X_{t-1}\big) \geq \nu_x \quad \text{ for all } t=1,2,\dots
\end{equation}
where $\nu_x\in [0,1]$.

Consider a sequence of binary random variables $\{Y_t\}_t$ such that If $Y_t=1$, then $X_t=x$, i.e.,  $Y_t\leq 1\{X_t=x\}$, for all $t=1,2,\dots$

Could you help me to show that
\begin{equation}
\\Pr\big(X_t=x \, | \, Y_{1},\dots, Y_{t-1}\big) \geq   \nu_x  \quad \text{ for all } t=1,2,\dots \quad ?
\end{equation}

Comment: Ah, I wasn't reading closely enough.  My apologies!!!

Comment: thanks, I've just done it

Comment: What is the source of this proposition?

Comment: @Zhanxiong welcome back! Haven’t seen you on here in a while.

Comment: @mhdadk :) Life just becomes busier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is false, as can be disproved by the following counterexample.

Set the probability space $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $P(\{i\}) = 1/4$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$. Let $A_1 = \{1\}$, $A_2 = \{2\}$, $B_1 = \{1, 2\}$, $B_2 = \{2, 3\}$. Define $X_t = I_{B_t}, Y_t = I_{A_t}, t = 1, 2$ and take $x = 1$, $\nu_x = 1/2$.

It can be easily verified that $Y_t \leq X_t = I_{\{X_t = 1\}}$, hence the condition in the claim is satisfied.  However, while
\begin{align}
P(X_2 = 1|X_1) = P(B_2|B_1)I_{B_1} + P(B_2|B_1^c)I_{B_1^c} = \frac{1}{2} \geq \nu_x,
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
P(X_2 = 1|Y_1) = P(B_2|A_1)I_{A_1} + P(B_2|A_1^c)I_{A_1^c} = \frac{2}{3}I_{A_1^c}.
\end{align}
This means that for $\omega = 1$, $P(X_2 = 1|Y_1)(\omega) = 0$, fails to be greater than $1/2$.

Comment: I cannot award the bounty yet, will do it as soon as the system allows me. I've posted a related question, in case you could help again. Thanks! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626443/implications-of-pr-bigx-n-x-x-1-dots-x-n-1-big-geq-a